# How do i make a string of only one backslash? For example s = "\"

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am working on a project and to make a new path I needed backslash as a string.

So far I've tried `S = "\"`, but it didn't work.

This code snippet might help you to understand the situation.

```
dir_num = "1566510932"
reduced_base_directory = phosphogly_ws_len_path + r"\" + dir_num + r".result" + r"\" + dir_num + r".fas."
```

Comment: escape the backslash? S = '\\'

Comment: For path separator, you should use `os.sep` though

Comment: The *representation* of `"\\"` is `'\\'`, but it's still a single character: `len("\\") == 1`.

Comment: The problem with `r"\"` is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (at the end of the linked section): "Specifically,*a raw literal cannot end in a single backslash* (since the backslash would escape the following quote character)."

Comment: Thanks, it worked. @OlivierMelançon

Comment: It is better to use forward slashes for a [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it an extra slash:

```
S="\\"
```

Comment: @DiptoPaulDip No, it doesn't. It produces a string whose string *representation* contains a double backslash.